# Facebook: What is value of Id in the response sent by the Facebook Server on the real time change on user object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook app of type Webhook for subscribing user object on real time change notification. Now, when there is any change on user, the Facebook sends notification on the callback_url as expected.
When analyzed the JSON response sent by the user, it is observed that the value of id and uid is not the actual id of the user.

Sample JSON response sent by Facebook Server on real time change on the user:

```
{
   "entry":[
      {
         "time":1465984591,
         "id":"10210029053629744",
         "changed_fields":[
            "feed"
         ],
         "uid":"10210029053629744"
      }
   ],
   "object":"user"
}
```

The value 10210029053629744  is not id of the user.

What does the value of id\uid mean? How do we derive the actual user id from that id?

Comment: It’s the app-scoped user id, that is specific to your app. You don’t get the user’s “global” id any more, and there is no way to convert one into the other.

Comment: Yes. We never get the user's global id. We have to deal with only the app-scoped user id. Thanks.

Comment: @Pen you should save the app scope id for any reference with the user